# How do I tell Eclipse to not package JUnit and JMock for Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I use JUnit and JMock for testing in an Android project. Lately I've noticed that the Android builder included in Eclipse seems to package them as part of my Android application. Is there a way to tell Eclipse/Android plugin to ignore source folders and libraries when packaging .apk?

Comment: You can use ProGuard to strip unused classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the test class in the same project as your app? Try to create a seperate project Android Test Project project for the test stuff (File | New | Project | Android Test Project). This is how I run my tests.

Comment: You mean to put "business logic" in a separate project and import a jar? Hmm, that may work...

Comment: Have one project with everything you want to package with your app and have a second project of type Android Test Project with the testing stuff. I think this is the intended usage.

Comment: I think Android Test Project is more a "system test" thing - for testing the application as a whole. I have some classes that do not require Android at all (they are pure Java with some third-party libraries) - I'll separate those in a Maven project and then I can include any testing jars I want. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: This thread has good information  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps